# O que significa esse erro após a chamada da função openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, openssl

Ao chamar a função `openssl_encrypt`, sempre é retornado false. Ao verificar a função `openssl_error_string`, recebo o seguinte erro:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

O código que estou fazendo os testes é esse:

```
$data = 'Olá, Wallace!';

$encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

if (false === $encrypted) {

    var_dump(openssl_error_string());

    exit;
}
```

Por que esse erro é gerado?

Estou fazendo esses testes tentando encontra uma solução para essa pergunta:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185919/erro-de-encripta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel-ap%C3%B3s-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-php-could-not-encrypt-the-d

Comment: Olá, eu rodei o código aqui e funcionou certinho, Ubuntu com PHP 7.0. Qual SO e versão do PHP que você está usando?

Comment: Eu estava utilizando a versão 5.6 do PHP

Comment: Olá, e qual SO-Sistema Operacional?

Comment: Meu SO é Linux, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Idem aqui, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits, mas pelo que conheço, a versão padrão que vem do PHP é a 7, rodei o código aqui e funciona legal, como você está na versão 5.6 deve ter alterado alguma configuração e talvez passou a gerar este erro?